# Counting Fields in Relation to their Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the correct SQL to perform my task. I am trying to find the count of all actors that all act in the same movie. For all the movies. My SQL statement to fetch the film title and the first and last name of each actor is.

```
SELECT title, actor.first_name, actor.last_name, 
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
ORDER BY film.title
```

My database returns this :

[image: Return of SQL Query]

As you can see there are 10 actors belonging to the movie title ACADEMY DINOSAUR. What is the SQL that would provide me with a number of actors for each film?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Add `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY file.title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL can be like this

```
SELECT title, count(1) COUNT 
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id 
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id 
GROUP BY title
```

Comment: This should be incorrect. `GROUP BY` should not include `actor.first_name, actor.last_name`.

Comment: SELECT title, count(1) COUNT
    FROM film
    INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
    INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
    GROUP BY title

Comment: Please place the correct code (by using [edit]) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this

```
select tt.title, count(1) from (
SELECT title, actor.first_name, actor.last_name, 
     FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
) tt group by tt.title
ORDER BY tt.title
```

Comment: I'm not so sure abount which would be faster between [subquery] and [inner join], [subquery] would excute sql for every data, but [inner join] would take more memory. When you are not good at group by, I think the sql with [subquery] below will be better for you: 
select title
,(select count(1) from film_actor where film_actor.film_id = film.film_id) as tCount 
from film